# Google glass voice recognition

Tags: java, android, android-intent, google-glass, voice-recognition

I want to do a google glass application that can recognize the words said by others to you.
I tries to use the same Android code for voice recognition

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
Intent i = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
         i.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, "en-US");
             try {
             startActivityForResult(i, REQUEST_OK);
         } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Error initializing speech to text engine.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         }
}
```

This didn't work because, this code recognizes only the speech the person putting the glass on his head is saying.
I need my application to also recognize the voice of others talks to me.

Anyone could help please?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the other person is close enough of the microphone, it should work.

The problem here is about the hardware not the code, the microphone is only receiving the voice of the person around it, if you are too far it won't work.

Comment: you are completely right, but how the video records the sounds even when they are 2-3 meters far from you? i thought to record a video and then to analyze the sound was recorded, but then i found that we can't save recorded videos and sounds to the glass memory!
I'm still confused and without an answer :(

Thank you anyway dear

Comment: I am am not an expert in this field, but when you analyse a sound you specify a minimum volume to be able to start the recognition. I guess Google specify that you need to be around 1 meter from the glass to start the voice recognition, but if you yell it could be 1.5meters... As I said, it depend on the volume of your voice.